# Stuck with Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - Terminal, Mac

Tags: mysql, terminal

I am stuck when trying to access mysql. It's my first time so please be patient with me.

Initially I was try to set up Ruby and Rails and everything worked perfrectly expect access denied when connecting to the server, SO I ran this command.

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

I've tried various passwords including leaving it blank and get this error.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I am assuming I need to reset the password for root user but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One method:

1. stop your MySQL server.
2. start your MySQL server with the `--skip-grant-tables` option. It allows you to connect to the server without a password.

   ```
   /path/to/mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
   ```
3. connect to your server using the mysql client:

   ```
   mysql
   ```
4. change the root password (replace *NewPassord* by what you want):

   ```
   UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('NewPassord') WHERE user='root';
   ```
5. restart yout MySQL server.

There are others ways to reset the MySQL root password:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I dont have any database named `mysql`, I have two databases: `information_schema` and `test`. I connected through this command: ` mysql -h127.0.0.1` as via just `mysql` I was getting this err: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: In my case I got the following error : 

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'.

For that, I checked user table structure and realised that column name is 'authentication_string'.

Followed this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692812/mysql-user-db-does-not-have-password-columns-installing-mysql-on-osx

Comment: I have tried sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables, but it doesn't work. this comman : /path/to/mysqld --skip-grant-tables & , works for me. Thx, my mac  is OSX10.11.6, mysql server5.7.17

Comment: @pennychan you have to replace `/path/to` with the actual path to the `mysqld` file. From the command line you can run `locate mysqld` and it will (probably) show you the path to that file.

Comment: @b_dubb Thx, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: /path/to/mysqld --skip-grant-tables &      results in:        [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

Comment: uninstalling mysql and installing with an installer helped me resolve it . 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67597173/6840615

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and this worked like a charm -

Later versions of mysql implement a newer authentication scheme, not all libraries are up to date with this. You can revert to classic authentication by adding the following entry into your my.cnf

```
[mysqld]

# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

# Some libraries not compatible with latest authentication scheme as per the SO article [1].
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Simply add the following in /private/etc/my.cnf

# Only allow connections from localhost 
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/ae7rf4/access_denied_for_user_rootlocalhost_mac_os/

Answer (score 0):

@Muur the last step did not worked for me(mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19) i had to change query to `update user set authentication_string=password('1111') where user='root';` `update user set password_expired=N where user='root';`