# MySQL on Mac: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed MySQL on my Mac following the guide at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-pkg.html

Then I downloaded MySQL and tried to connect to it, but I got the error:
[image]

I have tried to reset the root password as mentioned in [Stuck with Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - Terminal, Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896082/stuck-with-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-terminal-mac) but it does not help.