# Mac OS X - can´t access mysql via Terminal

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I installed MySQL on MacOS El Capitan. But I am not able to access it.

I get the error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user
>   'denismilosavljevic'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How do I properly connect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stuck with Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - Terminal, Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896082/stuck-with-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-terminal-mac)

Answer (score 0):

On OS X to start/stop/restart MySQL pre 5.7  from the command line:

```
 sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
 sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
 sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
```

If it is running then try mysql -u root -p

**Update :**

If still not working then set your path

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

& try again

`mysql -u root -p`

Comment: I did, then I get this error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: By default, the root user in MySQL doesn't have a password and can only connect from localhost. So /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot should work and  Please check your mysql path

Comment: Unfortunately no, I get error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: So, the problem came up after I installed mysql and close the pop up window which comes after installation where is written mysql password.

Then I tried to reset password what did not worked.

I installed mysql again, but it doesn´t seem to override existing files..

Comment: Opps... It may take a half hour more for you. But try to Remove all files related to mysql completely and reinstall it properly. On prompt of  password use simple password.